# SoapUI-5.4.0 on Windows: ExceptionInInitializerError during new settings creation?

Tags: java, soap, soapui, soap-client

Everything was working fine for an year but since yesterday my `SoapUI-5.4.0` is not starting-up. I tried un-installing and re-installing but same below mentioned issue persist. Then I tried standalone ZIP with and without Java versions, but same issue. Also `soapui-settings.xml` is not getting created at `C:\Users\user1` location. Can someone please guide here:

**Error logs**:

```
Configuring log4j from [C:\SoapUI-5.4.0\bin\soapui-log4j.xml]
10:10:11,339 INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] Creating new settings at [C:\Users\user1\soapui-settings.xml]
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport.<clinit>(HttpClientSupport.java:73)
        at com.eviware.soapui.DefaultSoapUICore.initSettings(DefaultSoapUICore.java:373)
        at com.eviware.soapui.DefaultSoapUICore.init(DefaultSoapUICore.java:141)
        at com.eviware.soapui.DefaultSoapUICore.<init>(DefaultSoapUICore.java:126)
        at com.eviware.soapui.DefaultSoapUICore.createDefault(DefaultSoapUICore.java:105)
        at com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.getSettings(SoapUI.java:1580)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is related to my proxy settings, after enabling proxy it works, weird!

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to be related to Proxy setting detection (on by default).
You can disable this by adding this to your soapui-settings.xml file located in User folder:

```
<con:setting id="ProxySettings@enableProxy">false</con:setting>
```